Failed update : 14: curl#52 - "Empty reply from server"
I try to run sudo yum update but getting error : Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#52 - "Empty reply from server"
I already added a proxy configuration in /etc/yum.conf since the connection to the Internet will be using a proxy server but still failed. I am using Centos, Linux 7 and I'm still new to this.
TQ

mirrorlist.centos.org does not exist anymore as Centos 7 has reached EOL 1st January 2024.
You should be able to use vault.centos.org instead of mirrorlist.centos.org.
More discussions on serverfault regarding this here
